# Meteor: resetPassword email link behavior

Tags: meteor, password-recovery

I'm trying to implement the "reset password" functionality in my Meteor app.  I have a very simple implementation of it based on this tutorial:  [Julien's tutorial on gentlenode](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-2-build-a-complete-registration-system/3)

There are several examples floating around that use this same basic approach.  I did mine almost exactly like Julien's but I used only one template; I use an {{#if}} in my template that displays the 'reset password' form, if my session variable sResetPassword is not falsey.  (I don't know how the correct template is supposed to get displayed in Julien's example and it doesn't work for me as it is written -- the template doesn't change.)

Here's the critical piece of code.  Two different methods that both work on my local app, but neither one works on my hosted (modulus) app.

```
/* method one
if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {
  Session.set('sResetPassword', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
}

/* method two
Accounts.onResetPasswordLink( function(token) { 
    Session.set('sResetPassword', token);  
});
```

On my deployed version (Modulus), the link opens up my app and just goes straight to the start screen.  When I check the value of my sResetPassword session var, it's undefined, so somehow the value of the token never gets put into the var.

While we're on the subject, does anyone know how you are supposed to get the correct template to load when you use a separate template for the reset password form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for whatever reason, replacing iron-router with flow-router fixed this issue for me.  I created a new app with only the login and reset password functionality and it worked fine.  I added iron-router and again it worked, but only dev mode.  When I ran it in production mode, the problem returned.  Replaced iron-router with flow-router (in both the test app and my full app) and now the problem is gone.  The email link works as expected in both modes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works for us. Code:

```
var token, done;

Accounts.onResetPasswordLink(function (t, d)
{
    token = t;
    done = d;
    setTimeout(()=>Router.go("reset_password"), 0);
});

Template["reset_password"].events({
    "click #resetBtn": function (event:Event, instance:Blaze.TemplateInstance)
    {
        var password1: string = instance.$("#input_password1").val();
        var password2: string = instance.$("#input_password2").val();
        console.log(password1, password2);
        if (password1 != password2)
        {
            return;
        }

        Accounts.resetPassword(token, password1, ()=>
        {
            done();
            Router.go("somewhere");
        });


    }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="reset_password">
<form data-parsley-validate>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="input_password1" type="password" class="validate" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-minlength="6" data-parsley-minlength-message = "Please provide a password that is at least a 6 characters long." required>
        <label for="input_password1">New Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input id="input_password2" type="password" class="validate" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-minlength="6" data-parsley-minlength-message = "Please provide a password that is at least a 6 characters long." required>
        <label for="input_password2">Again</label>
    </div>
    <button id="resetBtn" class="waves-effect btn">Reset Password</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, Michel H.  After looking at your code, I added a Router.go statement wrapped in a setTimeout().  And with that change, I did briefly see the right template after clicking on the link.  But then the app went right to the start screen.  So I'm still experimenting.  BTW, what is that interesting construction:  ()=>   in your code?  It doesn't compile for me.

Comment: Its a TypeScript thing, it preserves the outer "this" just use function() instead.