# Meteor: dev mode vs. production mode

Tags: meteor

From what I can tell, the main difference between running: meteor and running: meteor --production is the fact that the files are minimized before they are sent down to the client.  Are there other differences?  I can't understand why the app would behave differently when it's run with --production.

I'm battling an issue with the email link sent to users who need to have their password reset, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511241/meteor-resetpassword-email-link-behavior).  I thought it had something to do with modulus, but I've discovered that the problem is also present when I just run with meteor --production. I'm about ready to give up and implement a different method for password recovery, but I would like to understand better what's going on.  For instance, the password link is in this form:

http://localhost:3000/#/reset-password/8DcD4moapoBcs8qRYdJ-BE41ec2eIWr8Vrl99qBcD7T

What does that # do?  And does the reset-password string do anything?

Comment: This is not an answer, but doing a google search, this thread turned out... might be helpful: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/issues/410 .

Comment: and here is a duplicate SO question that offers a resolution, hope it works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130310/how-do-you-change-the-reset-password-url-in-meteor

Comment: Thanks, GPicazo.  I did a lot of research into this yesterday, but I actually didn't find either of those threads.  I did try changing the URL on the link, based on another post, but that didn't work out.  Apparently, iron-router had an issue with the # part of the URL a couple of years ago, but that seems to have been fixed.